# Spring Boot 2.0.3 Actuator with Spring Boot security CSRF invalid

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In a test project without security the Actuator works as expected. However in the "real" project it does not. The project does have a dependency of:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The rest of the app does work just cannot get the Actuator to work. IE I get a 403 error when going to the URL.

Additionally did set debug level in logging. Here's the lines I think matter.

```
 o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/uploadtest/**']]

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/uploadtest/**'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true

 o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : All requestMatchers returned true

 o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/actuator/env

 o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@3dfbb2f7

 w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.

 o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally

 s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

then later on:

```
 w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.

 yFilter$SessionRepositoryResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on

 yFilter$SessionRepositoryResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on

 o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Written [{timestamp=Thu Aug 30 18:59:42 UTC 2018, status=403, error=Forbidden, message=Forbidden, path=/actuator/env}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@6039e284]

 yFilter$SessionRepositoryResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on

 o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
```

Additionally looked on web and did add this class which I thought to disable security:

```
 import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.EndpointRequest;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
 import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
 import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

 @Order(101)
 @Configuration
 public class ActuatorSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

     @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint())
             .authorizeRequests()
             .anyRequest().permitAll();
     }


 }
```

So my question is what change do I need to do to get the Actuator to work while security is on?

a bit more of the log:

```
 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/env at position 1 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/env at position 2 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'

 w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists

 w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/env at position 3 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/env at position 4 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CorsAttributeFilter'

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/env at position 5 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CorsFilter'

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/env at position 6 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'

 o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/logout'

 o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /actuator/env' doesn't match 'POST /logout

 o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /actuator/env' doesn't match 'PUT /logout

 o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /actuator/env' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout

 o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/env at position 7 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/env at position 8 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/env at position 9 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/env at position 10 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'

 o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@7bccedb2: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/env at position 11 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/env at position 12 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/env at position 13 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/login'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/bower_components/**/*'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/app/**/*'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/index.html'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/home.html'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/signin.html'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/favicon.ico'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/user/**'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/test/**'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/cache/**'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/LitmusTest/**'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/uploadtest/**'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/rest/**'

 o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Public object - authentication not attempted

 o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'

 o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'authorizationAuditListener'

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/env at position 14 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'

 o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER               : A new session was created. To help you troubleshoot where the session was created we provided a StackTrace (this is not an error). You can prevent this from appearing by disabling DEBUG logging for org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.SESSION_LOGGER



 java.lang.RuntimeException: For debugging purposes only (not an error)

    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:367) [spring-session-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]

  big stack trace

 o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/']]

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true

 o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/login']]

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/login'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true

 o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/bower_components/**/*']]

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/bower_components/**/*'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true

 o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/app/**/*']]

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/app/**/*'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true

 o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/index.html']]

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/index.html'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true

 o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/home.html']]

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/home.html'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true

 o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/signin.html']]

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/signin.html'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true

 o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/favicon.ico']]

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/favicon.ico'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true

 o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/user/**']]

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/user/**'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true

 o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/test/**']]

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/test/**'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true

 o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/cache/**']]

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/cache/**'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true

 o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/LitmusTest/**']]

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/LitmusTest/**'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true

 o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/uploadtest/**']]

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/actuator/env'; against '/uploadtest/**'

 o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true

 o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : All requestMatchers returned true

 o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/actuator/env

 o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@3dfbb2f7

 w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.

 o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally

 s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 1 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 2 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'

 w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT

 w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$HttpSessionWrapper@77f87f2. A new one will be created.

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 3 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 4 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CorsAttributeFilter'

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 5 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CorsFilter'

 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 6 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
```

Comment: I did a little test project and everything works. how does your other web security configuration look like?

Comment: Oh I see. What's the order on your other websecurity configuratoin? this must be higher than 101

Comment: @Simion looking at some security code I do not see an Order annotation, how to tell? went to add more of log but stackoverflow did not seem to allow it.

Comment: @simon added to log since seems to infer position

Comment: based on what u inferred changed @Order(1) from @Order(101) .. the actuator then displayed. any links to what this is doing? seems like Spring orders security checks.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the csrf validation for a given url pattern by adding a line like this to your HttpSecurity-configuration:

```
.and().csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/actuator/**")
```

Since the actuator-endpoints are not state-changing CSRF is not a threat there.
[This answer on Stackexchange explains why](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/115810)

Comment: the link did not work but will look into what u said

Comment: Some standard Spring Boot actuator endpoints do change state, e.g., loggers, sessions, shutdown and startup. And I'd be reluctant to say that threaddump might not be an effective DoS target.